One parameter group, tangent bundle and vector field lift
I'm self studying the 'Differentiable Manifolds: A Theoretical Physics Approach' by  G. F. Torres del Castillo and I'm stuck on the exercise about one-parameter groups and vector lift:

Given one-parameter group of diffeomorphisms on $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$\{\phi_t = \left(e^{at}x, e^{bt}y \right) \}$, $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$,
find the one-parameter group induced by it on $T\mathbb{R}^2$ and show
its infinitesimal generator is: $$\overline{X} =aq_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial q_1} +
bq_2\frac{\partial}{\partial q_2} + a \frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{q}_1} + b \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}_2},$$
where $q_i, \dot{q}_i $ are coordinates in $T\mathbb{R}^2$ induced by Cartesian coordinates  $x,  y\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

I have a trouble with the second part - isn't it a mistake?. Here's my attempt:
I want to find $\overline{\phi_t}$, so let $p = (x_0,y_0)\in \mathbb{R}^2,\ v_p = (q^p_1, q^p_2, \dot{q}^p_1, \dot{q}^p_2) = (x_0, y_0, \dot{q}^p_1, \dot{q}^p_2) \in T_{\pi^{-1}(p)}\mathbb{R^2} \subset  T\mathbb{R}^2$. We want $\overline{\phi_t} (v_p)= \phi_{t*p}(v_p)$. Since $(\pi \circ \overline{\phi_t}) (v_p) = \phi_t (p)$, we know that first two coordinates of $\overline{\phi_t}(v_p)$ are $q_1 = e^{at}x_0,\ q_2 = e^{bt}y_o$.
Now more complicated part. I want to find $\dot{q_i}$ for $\overline{\phi_t}(v_p)$, so following definitions I have $$\dot{q_1}(\overline{\phi_t}(v_p)) = v_p(x_1(\phi_t(x_0))) = v_p(e^{at}{x_0}) = \dot{q}^p_1\frac{\partial (e^{at}x)}{\partial x}(p) + \dot{q^p_2}\frac{\partial (e^{at}x)}{\partial y}(p)  = \dot{q}^p_1 e^{at},$$
and by similar approach  $$\dot{q_1}(\overline{\phi_t}(v_p))  = \dot{q}^p_2 e^{bt}.$$
Therefore we conclude that the coordinates of $\overline{\phi_t}(v_p)$ are:
$$(q_1^pe^{at}, q_2^pe^{bt}, \dot{q}_1^pe^{at}, \dot{q}_2^pe^{bt})$$
Finally, infinitesimal generator, taking derivatives in $0$ with respect to $t$:
$$\overline{X}_{v_p} = q_1^pa \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial q_1}\right)_{v_p} + q_2^pb \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial q_2}\right)_{v_p} + \dot{q}_1^pa \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}_1}\right)_{v_p}+ \dot{q}_2^pb \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q}_2}\right)_{v_p} $$
So my question is - am I doing something wrong as I get the $\dot{q}_1^p,\ \dot{q}_2^p$ in two last coordinates of $\overline{X}_{v_p}$?
